# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location') in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

**The Error :**

i have this error that prevent me to fetch data from the html form, every time i fill the form with values , and hit the button that will send the data to an **API** that save the data to the database this error appears:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
    at /media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/routes/index.js:71:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at /media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/connect-ensure-login/lib/ensureLoggedIn.js:50:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

at first i said to myself maybe it's caused by the middleware so i add the some middelware in my **index.js** file :
**index.ejs:**

```html
<form action="/addNewHouse" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location" autocomplete="location" required>
    <input type="text" id="for" name="for" placeholder="For" autocomplete="for" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

**index.js:**

```js
var express = require('express');
var ensureLogIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var db = require('../db');

const app = express();
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.csrfToken();
  res.locals.csrfToken = token;
  next();
}
  );
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
var ensureLoggedIn = ensureLogIn();

function fetchTodos(req, res, next) {
  db.all('SELECT rowid AS id, * FROM houses WHERE owner_id = ?', [
    req.user.id,
    req.user.first_name
  ], function(err, rows) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    
    var todos = rows.map(function(row) {
      return {
        id: row.id,
        title: row.title,
        completed: row.completed == 1 ? true : false,
        url: '/' + row.id
      }
    });
    res.locals.todos = todos;
    res.locals.activeCount = todos.filter(function(todo) { return !todo.completed; }).length;
    res.locals.completedCount = todos.length - res.locals.activeCount;
    next();
  });
}

var router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      if (!req.user) { return res.render('home'); }
  next();
}, fetchTodos, function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.filter = null;
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});
/* GET THE LIST OF HOMES*/
router.get('/homes-list', (res,req) => {
  const homeList = "SELECT * FROM home WHERE owner_id = ?";
  db.all(homeList,[
    req.user.id
  ],
  (err , rows) =>{
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
    res.render("index/#house-list" , {module: rows})
  });
});
/*ADD NEW HOUSE*/
router.post('/addNewHouse', ensureLoggedIn ,(res,req , next) => {
    // const loc = req.body.location;
    // const toWhat = req.body.for; 
  const owner = 5;
  db.run('INSERT INTO home (owner_id,Location,for) VALUE( ? , ? , ? )',[
    owner,
    req.body.location,
    req.body.for
  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) { return console.error(err.message.at)}
  }),
  res.render('index');
  next();
});

// Get Sell Page
module.exports = router;
```

***all i want is to get the data form the form and save in the database***

**index.ejs file from the top:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Account • <%= user.username %> | Roshan</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon-0.png" type="image/png">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8a7299c2d2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="/img/Roshan-Logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check">
            <label for="check">
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
            </label>
            <div class="nav-btn">
                <label for="check">
                    <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>             
                </label>
                <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="center">
            
            <section>
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <li><button class="chang"><a href="#house-list">My List</a></button></li>
                    <li><button class="chang"><a href="#buy">Buy</a></button></li>
                    <li><button class="chang"><a href="#rent">Rent</a></button></li>
                    <li><button class="chang"><a href="#sell">Sell</a></button></li>
                </div>
                <div class="house-list" id="house-list">
                    <h1>House List</h1>
                
                    <form action="#">
                        
                        <input type="text" name="location" readonly>
                        <input type="text" name="space" readonly>
                        <input type="text" name="rooms" readonly>
                        <input type="text" name="status" readonly>
                        <input type="text" name="price" readonly>
            
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="house-list" id="buy">
                    <h1>Buy</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="house-list" id="rent">
                    <h1>rent</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="house-list" id="sell">
                    <h1>Add New House</h1>
                    <form action="/addNewHouse" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location" autocomplete="location" required>
                        <input type="text" id="for" name="for" placeholder="For" autocomplete="for" required>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
                        <input type="submit" value="Go">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

i hope you can help me

Comment: what is `console.log(req.body.location)` is outputting?

Comment: check your express version with `npm info express version`

Comment: @jkalandarov `console.log(req.body.location)` didn't give me any thing

Comment: @Seybsen the version is 4.18.1

Comment: try removing or commenting out `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Comment: I am starting to get suspicious about 
`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.csrfToken();
  res.locals.csrfToken = token;
  next();
}`
Because, you are not assigning `req.csrfToken()` as a value to `const token`. You're calling `csrfToken()` method of req object.

Comment: I commented all above code and still the same issue @jkalandarov

Comment: What will happan if i deleted it all and started over? @jkalandarov

Comment: Does `ensureLoggedIn` function do anything to req? It's being used as middleware and executed first when `'/addNewHouse'` endpoint is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have swapped `req` and `res` in your route declarations:

```
router.get('/homes-list', (res,req) { … })
                           ^^^^^^^ should be (req, res)

router.post('/addNewHouse', ensureLoggedIn ,(res,req , next) { … })
                                             ^^^^^^^ ditto
```

Comment: you was it start to give me another errors put i solved it and it's WORKING NOW